# How can I use a subquery that returns table names as table names in a Select Statement

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('last_update')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='testdatabase'
```

works fine, to return all tables needed.
Now I would like to use these tablenames as Input for another query to do the following SELECT statement:

```sql
SELECT MAX(last_update) FROM # <- here should be result of the first query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you describe in a single query. All SQL identifiers (e.g. table names) must be fixed at the time the query is parsed. There's no way to query a table whose name is not known until the query begins reading data.

You must do what you describe as two queries. The first to get the table name (as a string), and then in your client code, use that string to format a second query.